# Ignoring 0 Values from operation in SQL

Tags: jquery, sql, sql-server

I have a query where I select supplier code, supplier name, debit, credit, and debit minus credit as Final Balance.

How can I ignore 0 values for Final  Balance?

```
SELECT min(t1.ShortName), min(t0.cardname), 
    str(sum(t1.debit),15,2), str( sum(t1.Credit),13,2), 
    str(isnull(sum(T1.DEBIT) - abs(sum(T1.CREDIT)),0),13,2)[FINAL] 
FROM JDT1 t1 
INNER JOIN OCRD t0 ON t1.ShortName = t0.CardCode 
WHERE t0.CardType = 'S' AND year(t1.taxDate) = year(@Fecha)
GROUP BY t1.ShortName, t0.CardName
ORDER BY t1.ShortName
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is add to the having clause:

```
SELECT Min(t1.ShortName),
       Min(t0.cardname),
       Str(Sum(t1.debit), 15, 2),
       Str(Sum(t1.Credit), 13, 2),
       Str(Isnull(Sum(T1.DEBIT) - Abs(Sum(T1.CREDIT)), 0), 13, 2)[FINAL]

  FROM JDT1 t1
       INNER JOIN OCRD t0
               ON t1.ShortName = t0.CardCode
 WHERE t0.CardType = 'S'
   AND Year(t1.taxDate) = Year(@Fecha)
 GROUP BY t1.ShortName,
          t0.CardName
 having Str(Isnull(Sum(T1.DEBIT) - Abs(Sum(T1.CREDIT)), 0), 13, 2) <> 0 
 ORDER BY t1.ShortName
```

Comment: I get same error when comparing as an int, 
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '         0.00' to data type int.
and when I compare as a char I get same results, no change/ignore of 0's

Comment: Oh found it, i was keeping STR in my having clause

Answer (score 2):

Dump your results into a #temp table and then select from that table with a where clause with your condition, should look like this:

```
SELECT Min(t1.ShortName),
       Min(t0.cardname),
       Str(Sum(t1.debit), 15, 2),
       Str(Sum(t1.Credit), 13, 2),
       Str(Isnull(Sum(T1.DEBIT) - Abs(Sum(T1.CREDIT)), 0), 13, 2)[FINAL]
       into #temp
  FROM JDT1 t1
       INNER JOIN OCRD t0
               ON t1.ShortName = t0.CardCode
 WHERE t0.CardType = 'S'
   AND Year(t1.taxDate) = Year(@Fecha)
 GROUP BY t1.ShortName,
          t0.CardName
 ORDER BY t1.ShortName 

 SELECT * FROM #temp where FINAL <> '0'
```

Comment: I get the following error: 
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '  -2446290.95' to data type int.
Since I didn't create this database I'm having struggles even finding out values are not the type I thought/expected

Comment: And when running '0' I get the same results, no difference from results thrown

Comment: You might have cast the field,

WHERE cast(FINAL as integer) <> 0

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I still get the same error

Comment: My FINAL has the STR clause thats why I keep getting the error, both solutions worked thanks